# Creating a Draft State in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Obligatory I'm new to coding acknowledgment)

I've created a simple blog app with Rails and also using simple_for gem for my forms. I am trying to create a draft state, using two submit buttons. The ultimate goal would let the "Publish" button have the post seen by all users logged in or not on the index page, and the "Save as Draft" button would let only those who are logged in see the post. Here's what I have so far.

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="actions">
<p><%= f.submit "Publish", :name => "publish" %>
<%= f.submit "Save as Draft", :name => "draft" %></p>   </div>
```

posts_controller.rb: (Not really sure what to put in here)

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb: (Not really sure how to specify posts that were submitted with different values)

```
   <% @posts.reverse_each do |post| %>
      <h1 style="font-family: latohairline"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h1>
        <p style="margin-top: -20px"><small>Posted by <%= post.user.name %></small></p>
        <p><%= post.description.html_safe %></p>

        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <div><p><small><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> |
          <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></small></p></div>
        <% else %>
        <% end %>
```

post.rb: (Not sure if anything needs to be altered in the model, but including it just in case)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :title
    def to_param
      [id, title.parameterize].join("-")
    end
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :image

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true


  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image


end
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been Googling for hours, but without knowing all the right terms to search for I've ended up with zilch. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using multiple submit buttons for the same form, you have to check `params[:commit]`. This will be set to the name of the submit button, so in your controller you can check

```
if params[:commit] == 'draft'
  # save as a draft
else
  # save as published
end
```

Are you also confused on how to classify each post as a draft or not? I would probably just make boolean field on your model and then make a few scopes based on it:

```
scope :drafts, -> { where(draft: true) }
scope :published, -> { where(draft: false) }
```

So saving as a draft just means you set `draft` to true. Then you can use `Post.drafts` or `Post.published` to retrieve either set to display them whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Draft logic can end up being pretty darn complex, especially if you want to track drafted updates after initially publishing. (Let's say I publish a record but then start making edits to it that I don't want yet to publish.)

I've started extracting draft logic into a Ruby gem called [Draftsman](https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman) if you want to give it a try.

I'm always open to answering questions or receiving feedback on suggestions on how to make it better. Drafts are an important part of my project, so I want for this API to be good!